# How to make App compatible with latest devices

Tags: codenameone

[image]For Android to make App compatible with the latest devices, we need to update in codename_settings file with the latest android version. Ex: codename1.arg.android.targetSdkVersion and codename1.arg.android.buildToolsVersion

1. I have tried with 33.0.5 and 34.0.5. With 34.0.5 build is failing. With 33.0.5, I'm able to build the App but on the device, it shows that "App isn't available for your device and it was made for an older version of Android"
2. Do we have a similar setting for IOS, how to make the App compatible with all devices? is it by default?

Please help here !! Also, you can guide me with a link where in codenameone this information is available.

Answer (score 0):

We always update to the latest version based on requirements by Google. The current target since August has been 33 ([see this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/requirements/target-sdk)) which is the maximum version we support.

When 34 becomes a valid target we will address that. I'm assuming that this isn't because of the 33 target but rather because of the minimum supported target or some other build hint. For that I will need to see that `android.*` build hints you have in place and the libraries that you use.

Comment: is it 33.0.0 ? what is the version if we need to update in settings file.

Comment: i have added screenshot android in the post please let me know. Issue here is with uploading the build into internal testing of google play. If i install directly from build tool it is working on android phone

Comment: You don't need to define 33 as this is already the default. I suggest checking out [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/cn1/comments/17yrdsf/improving_legacy_android_builds/) and including `android.useGradle8=true`. If you're getting a device error message then we need more information about the specific device (vendor, make etc.) and the Android version running on it. Does it print something to logcat when you try to install?

Comment: got it. it is not allowing me to install it as it says the App is designed for older versions of android. I'm testing on Samsung Galaxy S21 with latest OS

Comment: S21 isn't new and Android 13 is API level 33 which should be the default. I suggest removing the buildToolsVersion, useAndroidX, minPlayServices, targetSDKVersion hints. Instead just add the `android.useGradle8=true` hint and see if that solves the issue. Just to be clear, leave the `maps=true` hint and the permissions hint.